# What does len(contour) means?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been working under the image of bacteria and a wish to take the number of bacteria from the image, and also need to classify the bacteria with specific shape and size.
I am using opencv python. Now i use the contour method.

```
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dst,1,2)
    cnt = contours[0]
    l = len(contours)
    print l
    li = list(contours)
    print li
```

This give an output of l= 115 and li= some array values .
What does this means??

please help me in finding out the answer..e.coli image below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Contours connects continuous points and puts all of them in an array. So each element in this array probably corresponds to a different bacteria (or a false detection, due to a connected color group that is a shadow etc).

When you say `len(contours)`, you get the number of elements in this array. Therefore, you get a rough estimation of the number of bacterias.

In your case, there are 115 bacterias, or colors that are different than their surroundings which may or may not be bacterias. When you define a list for them and print the list, you get the properties of each element in this list, therefore you get the properties for each "connected point group" or each "object that is possibly a bacteria". Its all pretty straightforward really.

**If you realize that you have many false detections here is what you do:**

- A group of bacterias appearing as one:

  You threshold the image (convert it to black&white) and use the `erode` function first. Then use `dilate` function to remove their connections. Then go with `findContours` once more.
- Stains detected as bacterias:

  Make your thresholding only cover the bacterias color range, so everything else will be ignored.

See sources below, they might help:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.findCountours` returns a list of contours where each contour is a numpy array of points (2 columns for x, y coordinates). `len(foo)` is the length of list `foo`. So in your case it found 115 contours and your `li` is just a copy of the `contours` list.

You can easily examine the contours by using the [`drawContours` function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontour#cv2.drawContours).

```
# draws contours in white color, outlines only (not filled)
cv2.drawContours(dst, contours, -1, (255,))

cv2.imshow("result", dst)
cv2.waitKey(-1)
```